# Подключение внешних .jar библиотек в проекте на Play! Framework

Tags: java, библиотеки, jar, playframework

Требуется использовать некое стороннее API в виде .jar файла в проекте, разрабатываемом на фреймворке Play! Framework за версией 1.1 (здесь принципиально). Как и куда класть файл библиотеки в проекте, как его там зарегистрировать, дабы потом пользоваться этим API в коде проекта?

Answer (score 1):

В директорию *lib* проекта.

Comment: Сделал по такой схеме. В коде вызывающего класса import'ы не работают (или не видятся) при рантайме.. Что я делаю не так? Структура API по пакетам такова: net, util, models, org.json. Простенький код ниже:


    package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import net.ResourceProvider;
import net.SimpleHttpClient;

public class HelpProvider extends Controller {
  
  public static void getHelp() {
 SimpleHttpClient http = new SimpleHttpClient("http://localhost", "9000");
 ResourceProvider resourceProvider = new ResourcrProvider(http);
 
  renderText("Null help at now..");
 
  }

}

Comment: При этом, ошибка такого рода, что мол, не видятся такие пакеты и классы где либо в проекте..


    Error raised is : The import net.ResourceProvider cannot be resolved

Comment: clean и eclipsify (или другое, в зависимости от используемой IDE) сделали, после добавления jar'а?

Comment: Никак нет. Сейчас попробуем..

Comment: Сделал. Не работает. По прежнему такие же ошибки